# Android - how to get map coordinates from map view

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2

In my application I am displaying places using markers on google maps. But I am marking all the available places at once which I don't want to do. I wanted to display the places which only fits into the screen by fetching the maps coordinates as shown below:

[image]

I wanted only to fetch the places that are available in this range from the source by sending the coordinates of the maps. I am not sure whether I should capture all the 4-coordinates from the corners of the screen?

Can anyone help me to figure out this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get those by using this method:

```
    yourMapView.getMap().getCameraPosition();
```

This returns you a [CameraPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html) object. The coordinates of the camera is given by the field  **target** and the zoom level by the field **zoom**. Now you should be able to calculate the aproximate coordinates of the screen corners.

Comment: thanks Zarkaos. I am still confused with what to do? does this link have something to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985487/android-opengl-es-2-0-screen-coordinates-to-world-coordinates

Comment: I'm not an expert with using maps in Android :s But your link seems to be for a diffrent situation with OpenGl. I don't tink you can use it in your application..

Comment: ok. after obtaining camera position how can i resolve this into lat lon values? because i guess i should compare this lat lon value with the other places lat lon values in my database.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have the field  target in the CameraPosition which gives you a LatLng object. Refer to [LatLng reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) for getting lon and lat values from LatLng object.

Comment: I tried with your solution. It is returning the lat lon values of the center of the screen

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the TopLeft and BottomRight coordinates of the map at any time, use the following:

```
public GeoPoint getCurrentTL(MapView map){
    Projection pr = map.getProjection();
    return pr.fromPixels(0, 0);
}

public GeoPoint getCurrentBR(MapView map){
    Projection pr = map.getProjection();
    return pr.fromPixels(map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. see whether you have something to comment on Zarkoas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is an old question, but here's a fresh take on the issue.

You can ask for the visible region when the map is up (visible) with:

```
VisibleRegion vRegion = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
LatLng upperLeft = vRegion.farLeft
LatLng lowerRight = vRegion.nearRight;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way, we can use **[LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds)**. It returns ***2 points: northeast and southwest***.

> VisibleRegion vRegion = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
>     LatLng southwest = vRegion.latLngBounds.southwest;
>     LatLng northeast = vRegion.latLngBounds.northeast;

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views